# Significant difference between percentage values

Tags: statistical-significance

I am trying to find significant difference among hormone treatments in a tissue culture study. My data is a single percentage value for every hormone treatment. Can i analyse it using SPSS to find the best treatment? How? If not what is the way to analyse it?

Answer (score 1):

If I am on the right track then you have only one observation for each hormonal treatment and you want to test for is there any significant difference(for your values) among hormone treatment.

For this I can not help in SPSS but can definitely give you intuition for testing this.

First Plot your data for each hormonal treatment on the same graph and try to visualize is there any particular or conspicuous large enough differences in the values. If yes, I would say conduct experiment again only for that hormonal treatment and check for consistency of your results.

Second: statistically more intuitive, if there is no significant difference in hormonal treatment then all observations must have same mean. So first calculate mean and standard deviation and then either test individually for each value(not preferred statistically) or test collectively.

It would help you atleast make some inference about your data.